# How to prevent users from burning custom tokens?

Tags: assets, token, ico

Scenario:
Let's says Issuer has generated fixed supply of 1000 X tokens (i.e After generating 1000 X tokens the account has been locked). Now ICO is done for 500 X tokens. Among the participants of ICO one malicious participant transferred his 100 X tokens back to Issuer to attack the fixed supply. This will create a deficiency of 100 X tokens in total supply making the total supply now only 900 X token.

How to prevent such kind of malicious attacks?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. Once someone sends tokens to the issuing account, they are burned, and there is no way to prevent this.

Why do you think that it's a problem? You are calling it an "attack", while it's merely a standard deflation mechanics. There is a common practice among the blockchain projects to burn tokens surplus to increase the value of the circulating tokens, or adjust the governance.

And you can always issue more tokens if the issuer account wasn't permanently locked.

Comment: In this case yes the account is locked after the generating the fixed supply. So I call it as attack, as the issuer will not be able to further generate more tokens.

Comment: Unless he stole someone else's tokens and sent them back to the issuer, I don't see the maliciousness of it.